# Trouble installing Kurso de esperanto

Tags: software-installation

So I've been trying to install Kurso de esperanto using the official instructions and I keep getting the following error
"error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"
Any help is much appreciated

Edit: I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS,and I tried to run it from the instructions contained [here](http://kurso.com.br/elshuto.php?en)
Edit: I found this [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~mathieu-pellegrin/+archive/ubuntu/kurso-de-esperanto) I just have no idea how to install from it

Comment: Your version of Ubuntu is needed too; eg. https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libpng12 shows its available for Trusty (14.04) & Xenial (16.04)

Comment: Well it's running graphically now but has no sound or video and when I try to run it and launch it from the temrinal so it prints error messages there I get "WARNING: bool Phonon::FactoryPrivate::createBackend() phonon backend plugin could not be loaded"

Comment: When you provide more information (thanks for putting version info in question) its best to add it to your question (*its easily missed in comments*).  A quick scan of phonon online reveals https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&keywords=phonon but as I'm running 18.04 at the moment I looked and `phonon-backend*` was not installed on my box (possibly isn't on yours either). As for which it uses, maybe phonon-backend-gstreamer but I'm guessing.

Comment: Thanks for the help,It runs on QT so which are most likely to help (the app was made in 2013)